# How to include non react js javascript libraries in the laravel and react application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, laravel

I am new to react js. I am building one application using React and Larave but I don't know how to include non-react libraries into the react-laravel application. I have used the componentDidMount function to include the file, which is getting include in the document but it's not getting executed.

Comment: The `commandDidMount()` lifecycle hook is already React. Are you intending to use these libraries _inside_ of react of _separated_? If you're going to use them separately, don't mix their code with React lifecycle hooks. If you want to use them inside, keep in mind, that they mustn't change the DOM since it can confuse React because it has its own DOM.

Comment: It's hard to give you a precise answer since you mentioned `commandDidMount()` but didn't [provide any code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to understand what _exactly_ you're doing.

Comment: What library are you trying to include?

Answer (score 0):

With "componentDidMount" you are in a React component. You might have any non-React JavaScript code there, but React will only apply what it gets back from a component. It is not possible to add some "side effects" to React components, i.e. doing arbitrary JS additionally to React's rendering.